# Plotly Volume fig.show() doesnt display anything

Tags: python, plotly-python, volume, isosurface

I'm struggling with making Python Plotly to show a 3D volume plot (isosurface contours) in Spyder or Jupyter Notebook.

I am successful with a simple example copied from the web:

```py
import numpy as np   
import plotly.graph_objs as go

X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[-3:3:10j, -5:5:10j, -1:1:3j]

values = np.random.randint(100, size=300)

fig = go.Figure(go.Volume(x=X.flatten(),
                          y=Y.flatten(),
                          z=Z.flatten(),
                          value=values.flatten(),
                          opacity=1,
                          surface_count=21))
fig.show()
values
```

However, when I input my 3D numpy array of shape `(182,182,232)` and do the same, it does not do anything at all. No error, no figure plot (not even an empty one), nothing. But I have everything the same as in the example above, I define grid coordinates and then I input 1D flattened array as field values

```py
import numpy as np   
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import plotly.io as io
io.renderers.default='browser'

f = np.load('tomo.npy')

X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[-3:3:182j, -5:5:182j, -1:1:232j]

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Volume(
    x=X.flatten(), y=Y.flatten(), z=Z.flatten(),
    value=f.flatten(),
    opacity=1,
    surface_count=15,
    ))

fig.show()
```

I tried to change the renderer to the browser, and tried to do different min and max isosurfaces, to no avail. I am able to plot the 3D data with thus code:

```py
pl = pv.Plotter()
pl.add_volume(tomo, cmap="coolwarm", opacity="sigmoid", shade=True)
pl.camera_position = [(929.0, 1067.0, -278.9), (249.5, 234.5, 101.25), (-0.2048, -0.2632, -0.9427)]
pl.camera.zoom(1.5)
pl.show()
```

So the data is not corrupted.

Comment: may help: https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/plotly_python_isosurface.html